# Add line in svg using d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have five svg element:--

```
 <svg class="chart"  viewBox="0 0 960 500"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"> </svg>
```

I want to add lines in each svg. If i am doing the below:-

```
d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(branches)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', x1)
    .attr('y1', y1)
    .attr('x2', x2)
    .attr('y2', y2)
    .style('stroke-width', function(d) {return parseInt(maxDepth + 4 - d.d) + 'px';})
    .attr('id', function(d) {return 'id-'+d.i;})
    .on('mouseover', highlightParents)
    .on('mouseout', highlightParents)
    .on('click',value);
```

It will add line in first svg. I have seen some after googling. There is a .each loop in d3. How can i use this to add lines in my all svg's. I have seen in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218016/each-with-a-filter). But did not get any idea. plaese help me to add lines in more then one svg. Can i use class in svg to add line.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
d3.select(svg)
```

this will return only the first svg and add all the lines in it

if you want to add a different line into each svg

try doing

```
d3.selectAll('svg')
.data(branches)
.enter()
.append('line')
.attr('x1', x1)
.attr('y1', y1)
.attr('x2', x2)
.attr('y2', y2)
.style('stroke-width', function(d) {return parseInt(maxDepth + 4 - d.d) + 'px';})
.attr('id', function(d) {return 'id-'+d.i;})
.on('mouseover', highlightParents)
.on('mouseout', highlightParents)
.on('click',value);
```

Comment: Actually i am using it in d3 tree http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/d3-tree/. I want to implement more then one tree in. But i can't get any idea...Please help me.

Comment: You need to use `d3.selectAll("svg").selectAll("line").data(branches)...`.